# Keep Find bar open across all other tabs in Firefox 25

Tags: windows, firefox, find, browser-tabs

Previously, the find bar (triggered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> which appears at the bottom) **used to stay active across all open tabs** with the search term retained. This is no longer the case with Firefox 25.

I have already edited `userChrome.css` file to restore previous design of the find bar using [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/976166) and [that](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css).

The missing functionality that I seek is:

1. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> keep the find bar open across all tabs until I voluntarily close it, in which case it should close across all other tabs automatically.
2. To show the **same search term** across all other open tabs.

Unfortunately, this behavior - which worked very well for [many](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/975375) - has been introduced as a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=537013).
Please note that I do not want an add-on as a solution, nor do I want to downgrade Firefox to a previous version.

I have also checked `about:config` for potential settings but to no avail.

Comment: F3 will open the Find bar.

Comment: @martineau I realize that. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use some Firefox extensions e.g.

- [Hugo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hugo/)
- [Findbar-Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/)
- [GlobalFindBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/globalfindbar/)

But it got a bit less practical

Comment: GlobalFindBar for me as well. I cannot see how anyone can suggest FindBar-Tweak as a solution. It's so heavy handed and the settings UI is woeful.