# Use the same "find bar" in all tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, find

Before, the "find bar" (what you get by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>) was the same for all tabs. But now it is separate per tab.

That is, if I write a word (e.g., "hello") in the bar, I go to another tab and I open the bar, after the word appears ("hello") and I change it (e.g., "goodbye"), and I come back to the previous page, it continues to be the same word ("hello").

I want to be able to configure Firefox that when I modify the "find bar" in a page, it modifies in all pages (somewhat like the way Internet Explorer works). How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I don't know English.

Comment: This behaviour was changed a long time ago ([Firefox 25](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/25.0/releasenotes/), released October 29, 2013)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep Find bar open across all other tabs in Firefox 25](http://superuser.com/questions/681197/keep-find-bar-open-across-all-other-tabs-in-firefox-25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [other SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/681197/keep-find-bar-open-across-all-other-tabs-in-firefox-25) is very similar.  There are a few add-ons listed there.  I found that FindBar Tweak worked for me.

- [GlobalFindBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/globalfindbar/)
- [FindBar Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/)
- [Hugo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hugo/)

Comment: When you find another SU question that appears to be the same, or has answers that also answer the current question, consider flagging the current question as a potential duplicate.  The will help others to find similar questions and related answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, the add-on [GlobalFindBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/globalfindbar/)
I use the find bar to edit in Wikipedia.